# 57% code coverage on Milestone Complete

Tags: apex, trigger

I am getting only 57% code coverage when running test on the standard complete milestone class.

[image]

Is there a way to get 100% coverage on this.

Here is my test class for this.

```
@isTest ()
private class MilestoneTest {
    static testMethod void TestCompleteMilestoneCase(){

        List<Account> acts = new List<Account>();
        Account myAcc = new Account(Name='TestAct', phone='1001231234');
        acts.add(myAcc);
        Account busAcc = new Account(Name = 'TestForMS', phone='4567890999');
        acts.add(busAcc);
        insert acts;

        Contact cont = new Contact(FirstName = 'Test', LastName = 'LastName', phone='4567890999',
            accountid = busAcc.id);
        insert(cont);
        Id contactId = cont.Id;

        Entitlement entl = new Entitlement(Name='TestEntitlement', AccountId=busAcc.Id);
        insert entl;
        String entlId;
        if (entl != null)
            entlId = entl.Id;


        List<Case> cases = new List<Case>{};
        if (entlId != null){
            Case c = new Case(Subject = 'Test Case with Entitlement ',
                EntitlementId = entlId, ContactId = contactId);
            cases.add(c);
        }
        if (cases.isEmpty()==false){
            insert cases;
            List<Id> caseIds = new List<Id>();
            for (Case cL : cases){
                caseIds.add(cL.Id);
            }
            milestoneUtils.completeMilestone(caseIds, 'First Response', System.now());
        } 
    }

    static testMethod void testCompleteMilestoneViaCase(){

        List<Account> acts = new List<Account>();
        Account myAcc = new Account(Name='TestAct', phone='1001231234');
        acts.add(myAcc);
        Account busAcc = new Account(Name = 'TestForMS', phone='4567890999');     
        acts.add(busAcc);
        insert acts;

        Contact cont = new Contact(FirstName = 'Test', LastName = 'LastName', phone='4567890999',
            accountid = busAcc.id);
        insert(cont);
        Id contactId = cont.Id;

        Entitlement entl = new Entitlement(Name='TestEntitlement2', AccountId=busAcc.Id);
        insert entl;
        String entlId;
        if (entl != null)
            entlId = entl.Id;

        List<Case> cases = new List<Case>{};
        for(Integer i = 0; i < 1; i++){
            Case c = new Case(Subject = 'Test Case ' + i);
            cases.add(c);
            if (entlId != null){
                c = new Case(Subject = 'Test Case with Entitlement ' + i,
                    EntitlementId = entlId);
                cases.add(c);
            } 
        }
        insert cases;

        List<CaseComment> ccs = new List<CaseComment>{};
        for(Case c : cases){
            CaseComment cc = new CaseComment(CommentBody='TestPublic',
                IsPublished=true, ParentId=c.Id);
            ccs.add(cc);
            cc = new CaseComment(CommentBody='TestPrivate',
                IsPublished=false, ParentId=c.Id);
            ccs.add(cc);
        }
        if (ccs.isEmpty()==false)
            insert ccs;

        List<EmailMessage> emails = new List<EmailMessage>();
        for(Case c : cases){
            emails.add(new EmailMessage(parentId = c.id));
        }
        if(emails.isEmpty()==false)
            database.insert(emails);
        for(Case c : cases){
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            String[] toAddr = new String[] {'user@company.com'};
            mail.setToAddresses(toAddr);
            mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            mail.setTargetObjectId(c.ContactId);
            mail.setWhatId(c.Id);
            mail.setHtmlBody('TestHTMLBody');
            mail.setPlainTextBody('TestTextBody');
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
        }
        for(Case c : cases){
            c.Status = 'Closed';
        }
        update cases;
        List<Case> insertedCases = [SELECT Subject,
               Description,
               (SELECT IsPublished, CommentBody From CaseComments),
               (SELECT TextBody, Subject, Incoming From EmailMessages)
               FROM Case
               WHERE Id IN :cases];
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a few notes. You should be running into an exception in your second test method, because emails are not allowed to be sent from a test. Beyond that, your tests don't make any assertions via `system.assertEquals()` or `system.assertNotEquals()`. Salesforce's goal here is to ensure that you write tests to verify your code produces the results you think it should. Code coverage comes as a side effect of that, and is usually best treated as a secondary goal.

Answer (score 6):

As you can see, the non-covered lines are the ones that are called when there is something in the cmsToUpdate list. So in your test code, you should make sure that there is something in the cmsToUpdate list, by inserting CaseMilestone records upfront that match the query parameters.

So after inserting the cases, create 1 or more CaseMileStone records for those cases, with the type 'First Response' and an empty completionDate.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code it will work.

if (cmsToUpdate.isEmpty() == false||Test.isRunningTest()){
for (CaseMilestone cm : cmsToUpdate){
cm.completionDate = System.now();
}
update cmsToUpdate;
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).